# Use Riemann integral to evaluate the limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{k}}{\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{n+k}}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, limits, riemann-integration

Use Riemann integral to evaluate the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt k}{\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{n+k}}$$

Comment: By Cesaro-Stolz, this limit is equal to the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{2n}+\sqrt{2n-1}-\sqrt{n}}=\frac1{2\sqrt2-1}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint. We have that
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{k}}{\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{n+k}}= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{\frac{k}{n}}}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n}}}
=
\frac{\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{\frac{k}{n}}}{\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n}}}=\frac{\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx}{\int_0^1 g(x)\, dx}.$$
What are the integrand functions $f$ and $g$? What is the final result?

Comment: Please edit your answer. In the last expression you wrote, somehow two question marks have appeared instead of algebraic quantities.

Comment: @Landon Carter The two question marks are intentional. My post is a hint...

Comment: @LandonCarter your comment is for real? The question marks are intented because RobertZ provide a hint, not a solution.

Comment: Oh I was thinking it was a problem with my browser.

Comment: Perhaps some other symbol besides ? could fit there: I also thought it was a typing mistake. It misleads.

Comment: @DonAntonio Is it better now?